# android activity inside fragment tab

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an app that contains three tabs, and I want to add an activity to tab1 but the only solution I found so far is to call intent within activity but the problem is when I click tab1 it open activity in new page but I want to open the activity inside fragment tab,

```
public class frag1 extends Fragment {
Context context; //Declare the variable context

@Nullable
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag1_layout, container, false);
    context = rootView.getContext(); // Assign your rootView to context

            //Pass the context and the Activity class you need to open from the Fragment Class, to the Intent
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, my_activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

    return rootView;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstand the meaning of Activity. Understand this as follows: one Activity - many fragments. In this case, you can only replace one fragment with another using `FragmentTransaction.replace()`.